# Please welcome two additional moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

It's only been a few months since the [last election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/3) and the moderators elected there hit the ground running, helping keep this site going strong.

[Willie](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/1543/willie-wong) and [Zev](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/264/zev-chonoles) recently told us that they'd like to take a bit of a break. Moderation has always been a strictly voluntary activity, so while they're taking a much deserved vacation, we're appointing the next two people chosen by you during the election to help share the workload:

[image: robjohn]
[image: mixedmath]

Please give them a warm welcome and be patient as they learn the ropes and come up to speed.

Comment: Welcome to the fold, gentlemen!

Comment: Welcome! Does this mean that Willie and Zev will remain moderator and they can resume their (very welcome) duties if they please?

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Barring them being absent for a really long time (think 6+ months), they're always welcome to return and resume their moderation duties.

Comment: @AdamLear Okay. Thanks, but if they decide to return, robjohn and mixedmath can still be moderators?

Comment: Finally. The Chatroom owner *has* some power to manage the chat.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Oh, absolutely. The more the merrier. :)

Comment: @AdamLear (Not serious): In that case I wonder why they were not immediately appointed 8-).

Comment: Welcome aboard you two.

Comment: O frabjous day! Callooh! Callay! The two users I have voted for are finally moderators!

Comment: welcome, The moderators

Answer (score 45):

[image: Yep...]

Thanks, robjohn for being so cool and knowledgeable.

Comment: +1 for making me grin.

Comment: Y'all better give the mean square his due!  Congrats on being chosen, robjohn.

Answer (score 2):

[We can all learn a lot from your calm and collective style.](https://encrypted-tbn3.google.com/images?q=tbn%3aANd9GcS1tNCW-7IjqmqCB2kNLE8OTJITdwK1ue-LiJKAosKF6hDCEAhTtA) 
Congratulations robjohn & mixedmath. Also congrats to anon on becoming co-owner of the math chat room.

Comment: At the risk of doing it myself: *please don't feed the trolls, people!*

Comment: @TheChaz Trolls also have feelings.

Comment: skullpatrol, your new avatar made me smile... not enough for an upvote, though :D (@Jonas, hopefully this means that sp has taken my comment in the lighthearted tone I intended!)