# History of Math.StackExchange

Tags: discussion, faq, statistics

This thread is used to record significant events in the life of Math.StackExchange.

*What should be recorded?* Creation of the site (proposed, beta tested, graduated). Technological innovations like TeX support and chat. Chronology of moderators. Base-10 milestones ($10^k$ users, $10^k$ questions, etc). Probably something else that I can't think of now. But nothing subjective or potentially inflammatory.

*How could it be useful?* Newcomers to the site will have a way to satisfy natural curiosity. Wikipedia editors  will have a convenient source of information about Math.SE. Users reading old meta threads will be able to interpret them properly, knowing that a certain post was written when its author was/was not a moderator. Former moderators will have their work formally recognized.

Comment: Should there also be some notes of questions and answers which hit high milestones, and users whose contribution hits high levels?

Comment: @MarkBennet Sure, record-setting questions and answers would be a good way to measure the widening reach of the site, if there is an objective measure (number of views?) to back up their inclusion. (By the way, I agree with [Noah Snyder](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1082/5/migrate-to-se-20/) that the Batman equation was a success story of Math.SE). I'm less sure about putting spotlight on particular users when it's not clear that they would like it. This is why I reworded the entry on Arturo's 100K to make it more about the site.

Comment: Should we include meta data as well?

Comment: @draks... I don't see a convincing reason to include meta in history. Pretty much all of its content (except faq) could disappear overnight without anyone losing anything of value.

Comment: The Maths Overflow post is located [here](http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/186/whats-the-story-behind-mathoverflow-/), now.

Comment: The link in the previous comment is now dead, here is a [Wayback Machine link](http://web.archive.org/web/20161024014230/http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/186/whats-the-story-behind-mathoverflow-/). (It is the topic "What’s the story behind mathoverflow?" from the old [tea](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/tea/info).) I will add that MO now also has a topic similar to this one: [History of MathOverflow](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/753).

Answer (score 85):

### Site Milestones

**June 2010**: Math.SE was proposed on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics) by [Dan Dumitru](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/88/dan-dumitru).

**July 2010**: Math.SE enters the beta phase. The first question was [What Does it Really Mean to Have Different Kinds of Infinities?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1/different-kinds-of-infinities) At least [60 users](https://math.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta) actively participated in the private beta (July 20-27). The most active users during the public beta phase (July 27-October 25) are [listed here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355?phase=beta&users=mostactive#tab-top).

**August 2010**: $1000^{\rm th}$ user joined.

**October 2010**: The site graduates from beta and [gets its own design](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/977/).

**November 2010**: First "Great Answer" badge awarded to [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan) for [Mathematical difference between white and black notes in a piano](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11669/mathematical-difference-between-white-and-black-notes-in-a-piano/11671#11671).

**December 2010**: First "Great Question" badge awarded to user [Chris](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1319/chris) for [Why can you turn clothing right-side-out?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755)

**January 2011**: $10000^{\rm th}$ answer posted.

**April 2011**: $10000^{\rm th}$ question posted.

**August 2011**: $10000^{\rm th}$ user joined.   [Is this Batman equation for real?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54506/79365) becomes the first question with $100000$ views.

**October 2011**: [First paper accepted for publication](http://dx.doi.org/10.4169/math.mag.86.1.039) (also [here](http://mathcs.pugetsound.edu/%7Emspivey/Exp.pdf)), based on a collaborative effort between math.SE users [Listing](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/3123/listing), [Peter Taylor](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5676/peter-taylor), [J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498), and [Mike Spivey](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/2370/mike-spivey) on Listing's question - [$n$th derivative of $e^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18284/).  Paper published in the February 2013 issue of *Mathematics Magazine*.

**December 2011**: [$\TeX$ support for chat](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3297) is introduced by [robjohn](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854/robjohn).

**January 2012**: Math.SE becomes the first SE 2.0 site with a 100K user ([Arturo Magidin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/742/arturo-magidin)), excluding Stack Overflow.

**August 2012**: $100000^{\rm th}$ answer posted. [J.M.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/498/) is the first user to [vote $10000 $ times](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4804/).

**January 2013**: [$100000^{\rm th}$ question posted:](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8289/congrats-math-stackexchange-com)  [Continuity of analytic function implies convergence of power series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/286119/)

**February 2013**: The [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag becomes the first tag to reach $10000$ questions.

**March 2013** was the first month with over $10000$ questions asked.

**July 2013**: The site becomes [third on SE](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) in the number of questions; first time an SE 2.0 site overtook a member of the [original trilogy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/) (ServerFault).

**October 2013**: [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/andre-nicolas) is the first user [to reach 200K](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11183/congratulations-to-andre-nicolas) reputation.

**November 2013**: The site becomes [second on SE](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questions) in the number of questions, [trailing only StackOverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORDMp.png).

**January 2014**: [$100000^{\rm th}$  user joined](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/170684/users-created-by-given-date?Date=2014-01-22).

**June 2014**: The [Official Math.SE Blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/) launched.

**August 2014**: The [homework](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homework) tag is [burninated and blacklisted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/fate-of-the-homework-tag-the-community-voted-now-what).

**October 2014**: [Post $\#1{,}000{,}000$ appears](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1000000/), an answer by [mjqxxxx](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/5546/mjqxxxx).

**November 2014**: [Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11667/michael-hardy) is the first user to make [$10000$ edits](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18561177#18561177). [André Nicolas](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6312/) is the first user [to reach 300K](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/17439/) reputation.

**January 2015**: [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232/qiaochu-yuan?tab=activity&sort=badges) is the first user to collect $1000$ (non-unique) badges.

**October 2015**: $500{,}000$ questions; the mark was reached on October 10.

**January 2016**: The Student badge becomes the first badge to be awarded $100{,}000$ times; the mark was reached on January 4.

**December 2016**: The $1{,}000{,}000^{\rm th}$ answer was posted.

**October 2018**: [The $1{,}000{,}000^{\rm th}$ question was posted](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1048994857459507200), titled:  [Separation Properties in Topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946014/). Math.SE is the first SE 2.0 site to reach 1 million questions.

**February 2023**: The number of undeleted users surpasses 1,000,000.

Comment: I remember the Batman equation post. There was a surge in views, partly because someone had created a referral link in Hacker News.

Comment: "June 2014: The Official Math.SE Blog launched." Should there also be an entry for the month during which the blog sank?

Comment: Nice. The `homework` tag is in the history books.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to name *that* as the 1000000th question. I can on a whim delete a few hundred questions and change the status of this. Or undelete a bunch and also change that.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There is a longer discussion on what is to be considered the 1,000,000th question on https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29230/identify-our-millionth-question/29242#29242 . At the time it was posted,  *Separation Properties in Topology*  was the 1,000,000th question - nothing more is claimed.

Comment: @GerryMyerson See: [We will no longer be hosting Blog Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291741), posted on [metase] in March 2017.

Comment: @mathlander What do you mean by "the number of users surpasses 1,000,000"? User number 1 million is blank (likely destroyed), but user 1,000,001 has been registered [for over a year](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1000001/yiheng-du).

Comment: @mathlander Thanks for the clarification - could you add some more description of what you mean by "the number of users" to the post? Also, no need to tag me and let me know who the latest user is, I can find that out myself.

Comment: I wanted to add a meaningful comment and tag you (since I forgot to do that yesterday).

Answer (score 41):

## Those who have served as site moderators

- [Isaac](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72) ([appointed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) moderator *pro tempore*, August 2010—December 2010)
- [Jamie Banks](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/76) ([appointed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) moderator *pro tempore*, August 2010—December 2010)
- [Larry Wang](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/73) ([appointed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) moderator *pro tempore*, August 2010—December 2010)
- [kennytm](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/171) ([appointed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/441/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) moderator *pro tempore*, August 2010—December 2010)
- [Qiaochu Yuan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/232) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1) moderator, December 2010—May 2013)
- [Robin Chapman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/226) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1) moderator, December 2010—December 2011)
- [Willie Wong](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1543) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1) moderator, December 2010—December 2014)
- [Akhil Mathew](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/536) ([called up](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1582/continuity-of-moderation/1588#1588) as moderator following [previous election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/1), February 2011—April 2011)
- [Zev Chonoles](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/264) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/2) moderator, June 2011—May 2013)
- [Mariano Suárez-Alvarez](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/274) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/2) moderator, June 2011—August 2018)
- [Eric Naslund](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6075) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/3) moderator, May 2012—May 2013)
- [Bill Dubuque](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/242) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/3) moderator, May 2012—December 2012)
- [**robjohn ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/13854) ([called up](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4831/please-welcome-two-additional-moderators) as moderator following [previous election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/3), August 2012—*present*)
- [**davidlowryduda ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/9754) ([called up](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4831/please-welcome-two-additional-moderators) as moderator following [previous election](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/3), August 2012—*present*)
- [**Alexander Gruber ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12952) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/4) moderator, May 2013—*present*)
- [Alex Becker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8173) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/4) moderator, May 2013—December 2014)
- [Michael Greinecker](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21674) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/4) moderator, May 2013—November 2021)
- [user642796](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/4) moderator, May 2013—October 2017)
- [**Pedro Tamaroff ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23350) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5) moderator, December 2014—*present*)
- [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5) moderator, December 2014—June 2018)
- [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/5) moderator, December 2014—March 2019; October 2019—August 2021)
- [**quid ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/85306) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/6) moderator, October 2017—*present*)
- [Jack D'Aurizio](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44121) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/6) moderator, October 2017—October 2018)
- [**Asaf Karagila ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7) moderator, August 2018—*present*)
- [**Aloizio Macedo ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/59234) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/7) moderator, August 2018—*present*)
- [**Xander Henderson ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/468350) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/8) moderator, August 2020—*present*)
- [**TheSimpliFire ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/471884) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9) moderator, November 2021—*present*)
- [**Paramanand Singh ♦**](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/72031) ([elected](https://math.stackexchange.com/election/9) moderator, November 2021—*present*)

### Timeline of site moderators

[image: Moderators August 2010—December 2021]

(Look at the source of this post for the $\LaTeX$ code that generated this image.)

Comment: BTW it would be nice to have some history available just on http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators — maybe we should add a feature request

Comment: @GrigoryM [There is such a request now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/258391/).

Comment: @Najib FYI, I adapted this for [SO moderators](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311059).

Comment: What happened to Daniel from March 2019 to October 2019?

Comment: @Jack moderator-status is revoked after a period of prolonged inactivity and reinstated upon return.

Comment: @GrigoryM SE is now considering creating a moderator history page: see [What do you think about adding a Former Moderators page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/371293) on [metase].

Answer (score 12):

According to my screenshot, the 1 millionth question was just posted today by Firat Celebi

[image]

Sadly, like those counts of who is the millionth person to walk over a bridge, I don't think there is actually any definitive answer to such a puzzle:  does one include questions that were deleted, or re-opened, or which were test posts, or duplicates etc etc etc (or in the bridge analogy, what about the person who walked half-way, then turned back etc)

Comment: I think this should be added to the main answer rather than as a new one (and personally I wouldn't mention the precise question).

Comment: @ArnaudD. I agree that it should be added to the Milestone answer. The screenshot could be in a [hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHLjd.png).

Comment: Please feel welcome to edit this into the main answer. Many thanks.

Comment: If one [includes all deleted questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/909485), the count as of the last dump to SEDE stood at 1,280,666.